# MATLAB path doesn't match pathdef

Tags: matlab, path, centos

I am running MATLAB 2013b on a CentOS machine. Right now I have `startup.m` set to `cd` me into another directory, lets call it `shared`, where I keep all of my code. I also have `pathdef.m` set to add `shared` and some of its subdirectories to the MATLAB path.

The problem is that once MATLAB is open and I check the path settings, `~/matlab` has also been added to the top of the path list, ahead of `shared`. The home folder is where I keep some old versions of code, so it causes the wrong version to be run sometimes. I've double checked my `pathdef` and `startup` files, and the `~/matlab` directory is definitely not listed. What could be causing MATLAB to automatically add this directory to the path, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If the home folder is mandatory, why not putting it in the path (using the designated tool in Matlab's preferences) but at the very bottom of the list. The shared folder will have the priority.

Comment: @Macduff I don't think it is mandatory, because this doesn't happen on a different machine. That makes me think there's a setting somewhere that needs to be changed